# What is the proper use of the name tag in the manifest file?

Tags: database, installation

In the latest J!3.4 when installing extension of type 'file' (or may be other types are affected also) there is a difference regarding what is going into `element` field of table `_extensions`.

Some extracts from 
`\libraries\cms\installer\adapter\file.php`

J!3.3.4:

```
$element = preg_replace('/\.xml/', '', basename($manifestPath));
```

Looks like filename is going to be stored into `element` field.

J!3.4.1:

```
$element = (string) $this->getManifest()->name;
$element = str_replace('files_', '', JFilterInput::getInstance()->clean($element, 'cmd'));
```

Now we have `name` tag into `element` field.

The problem comes when uninstalling such extension. In both cases Joomla is looking for manifest filename into `element` field. In the second case it will find name tage here.
Since Joomla [documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files) is saying:

```
<name> – raw component name (e.g. com_banners).
```

there should be no problem, except ugly names in Extension Manager. But some old extensions simply do not work now, as they do not have pure filenames in the `name` tag.

Because we have another [example](https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Making_non-core_language_packs) in Joomla Docs:

```
Put anything into here, name is only shown in extension manager. 
  <name>Kunena Language Pack</name>
```

So, what to write in the `name` tag when creating manifest files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For best understanding, you should check `com_banners` component. As you stated two ways to add `<name>` tag, both are ok to use and works well. In `<name>` tag you can write anything you prefer to, but as per document it should be `com_{compoentname}'. Let me give you two examples:

If you write like this:

```
<name>what ever</name>
```

`whate ever` will be the name of your component and will display same on both extension manager as well as on components menu.(Here I have intentionally ignored `<menu>` tag, that's out of the discussion for now.)

Where as if you write like below:

```
<name>com_componentname</name>
```

`com_componentname` will be the name of the component in extension manager as well as in components menu.

But here if you have used language file `en-GB.com_componentname.sys.ini` along with above `com_componentname` usage. You can specify language string for `com_componentname`. Joomla automatically searches for that name in relative language file.

```
COM_COMPONENTNAME="My whatever component"
```

and now this new language string `My whatever component` will display on both extension manager as well as on components menu. This is how it works.

> Language file does not allow language key to be separated by `white-space`. And I think that is why the usage of `<name>what ever</name>` does  display as it is.

Hope I am descriptive enough. :)

Comment: Thank you, working now. I have nice, translated name in the Extension Manager. But in the name tag you should have filename of the manifest file without .xml. If using the first approach - with white spaces ('what ever') you can not deinstall - File whatever.xml not found. At least this is true for type=file.

Comment: Correct. It checks without space when you try to uninstall it. Glade to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried with a file, but I suggest you do the following:

```
<name>files_helloworld</name>
```

Then in your administrator language "**.sys**" file, add the following:

```
HELLOWORLD="Hello World"
```

You see that I haven't used `FILES_` in the language string as this gets stripped.

Note, I have not tested this but I think it will works. Let me know what the outcome is.

Comment: Extension is named `files_helloworld`, not 'Hello World' in Extension Manager. Joomla can find manifest file helloworld.xml and can deinstall it. Table `_extensions`: Field 'name'='files_helloworld', field 'element'='helloworld'. There is something wrong, or something new and not documented with this type.